# is there any chance to stop audio play?

Tags: howler.js

I am stuck  and trying to stop audio play when switch to another playlist.
it keep playing the audio in home page
and when I click different track in different playlist it keep playing at home page.
and the end result is I could play 50 tracks at the same time but I would like play only one by one
no matter if it's pop beat or trap beat

Here is a video also  so you can understood little bit better what I am trying to say https://www.veed.io/view/0fdb7b06-4ec2-4770-8e16-982a036365b5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever resolved this.  This really should be a comment but I don't have a 50rep, so 'answer' was my only choice.  I'd confirm in your code that when a user clicks on a different playlist, you're doing:

```
// stop all howls playing
howler.stop();

// before starting the next, 'howl' being your next sound object to play
howl.play()
```

Comment: `howler` and `howl` look close enough to differ inadvertently.

Comment: (Circumventing thresholds is an adverse choice: You could have "saved" the question to answer it once you've  reached "50rep". Try to contribute something useful - an vote *useful* or *not useful* yourself.)

Comment: my thought was to help someone now rather than make them wait.  i won't hit 50 rep for a few years probably.  sorry, i'm not super familiar with how stackoverflow works.  we all started somewhere.  regardless, how is this not useful.  i scanned the posters code, and the suggestion would resolve it.